# Возможно ли при помощи функции CopyFile скопировать файл на другой ПК?

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты, прошу помочь с одной задачей: необходимо скопировать файл на другой  ПК, я подключен к нему по сетке. Указываю путь (куда нужно сохранить) \192.168.1.1\d\DB\,
но после копирования в этой папке пусто. Скажите, это вообще возможно? Может я путь неверно прописываю?

Comment: Да, дело было именно в слеше - глупо так) Спасибо:)

Comment: @АлександрЪ Бывает :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй слеш в начале потеряли. **\\**192.168.1.1\d\DB\
У вас есть права на запись в эту папку? Свободного места там хватает?
Покажите код уже наконец, телепаты в отпуске :)